# Need to release intermediate views with popToRootViewController?

Tags: iphone, view, release, popviewcontroller

I am down at one point in my application that I reset the user to top screen by using popToRootViewController - and then adjust the position pushing new views. I am asking myself what happens with all intermediary views in between... should I properly loop through them to release/dispose of them and how?

I have a low memory crash and I think it could come from this.

Thanks for any help in advance

Cheers,
geebee

EDIT1: I understand now that this is done automatically - BUT:
1) are there cases it is not done...
2) what method should I call to really free them (I only want to keep the views up to 4 and anything after should be discarded).
I trust you guys but all indicates from the lives bytes growing that something is staying behind...
Thanks for your help

Comment: You should try using the "Leaks" instrument to find out why exactly your app's memory footprint is growing.

Comment: I did use leaks - and see it is growing... I also found out that when I was releasing the views I had written the class name instead of the instance name... not flagged by compiler and somehow difficult to see because the only difference in name was the letter in uppercase. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`popToRootViewController` will release all intermediate viewcontroller memory. [Check this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

When a view controller is poped from the stack it's automatically release so you don't have to manually go and release it. Since `popToRootViewController` pops every viewController from the stack until it reaches the top one you don't have to worry about releasing them manually.